# WSDL Generate Java Bean Skeleton VS Generate Client?

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere, ibm-rational

just want to ask what's the difference between **Generate Java Bean Skeleton VS Generate Client** in Java Eclipse/RAD? I created a wsdl but I'm not sure on what to use between the two. My goal is to have a webservice that will consume parameters then I will process those parameter and will return the result.

Hope you can help me on what should I used for the webservice

[image]

Comment: I've not used RAD in a while, but `Generate Java Bean Skeleton` should give you the a Web Service Provider stub class, that is need implementation in the form of a a Java Bean. `Generate Client` should generate all the necessary stub classes required for you to invoke a per-existing Web Service Provider. So based on what you've said, it sounds like you need `Generate Java Bean Skeleton` and then you can go and implement the Stub class.

Comment: @ThomasJohnson What about the JAX-RPC and JAX-WS?